# Pointing to multiple S3 buckets in s3boto

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

In `settings.py` I have:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static.mysite.com'
```

This is pointing to my S3 bucket `static.mysite.com` and works fine when I do `manage.py collectstatic`, it uploads all the static files to my bucket. However, I have another bucket which I use for different purposes and would like to use in certain areas of the website, for example if I have a model like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    myobject = models.ImageField(upload_to='my/folder')
```

Now when `Image.save()` is invoked, it will still upload the file to the S3 bucket in `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, however I want this `Image.save()` to be point to another S3 bucket. Any **clean** way of doing this? I don't want to change `settings.py` in run time nor implement any practices that violate the key principles of django, i.e. having a pluggable easy-to-change backend storage.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The cleanest way for you would be to create a subclass of S3BotoStorage, and override default bucket name in the init method.

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class MyS3Storage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket'] = getattr(settings, 'MY_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
        super(MyS3Storage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then specify this class as your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` and leave `STATICFILES_STORAGE` as it is, or vise versa.

Comment: Nice! Where do you recommend to place this class in?

Comment: Somewhere in your project. I usually have separate app where I keep all project-specific things.

Comment: I created `storages.py` in an app called `core`, how should I refer to `MYS3Storage` in `STATICFILES_STORAGE`?

Comment: The same way as if you would import it `core.storages.MYS3Storage`

Comment: Coming back to this question, there is always an error showing up when I do `python manage.py collectstatic`, it says `Error importing storage module core.storage_backends: "No module named backends.s3boto"`. It seems like an issue with the line `from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage`.

Comment: Solved the above issue, you can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430770/django-error-importing-storages-backends)

Comment: Couple of notes - the super() call should be to super(MyS3Storage, self).. etc, and I had to change the 'bucket_name' kwarg to 'bucket'.  Maybe it's changed?  Thanks :)

Comment: No need to do this; see the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419248/django-storages-with-multiple-s3-buckets for a slightly cleaner resolution.

Comment: For those needing it, the import fix for django>1.9 is `from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage`