# Django - Error importing storages.backends

Tags: django, django-storage

I have created a custom storage backend, the file is called `storages.py` and is placed in an app called `core`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class S3StaticBucket(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket_name'] = getattr(settings, 'static.mysite.com')
        super(S3BotoStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In `settings.py`, I have the follwing:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'core.storages.S3StaticBucket'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

When I try to do `python manage.py collectstatic` it shows the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing storage module core.storages: "No module named backends.s3boto"
```

And when I run `python manage.py shell` and try to import the same:

```
>>> 
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
>>>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to import a `core.storages.S3StaticBucket` in shell as well? Maybe you missed an `__init__.py` file there.

Comment: Just tried doing so, I got `ImportError: No module named backends.s3boto`. I do have an empty `__init__.py` in the app `core`.

Comment: Hm. Try to comment a `from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage` line in storages.py, and write instead a `import storages` and then in a following line `print storages.__file__`. Then import a `core.storages.S3StaticBucket` in shell. Then manually import `storages` in shell and print `storages.__file__`. If the paths differ - you have your answer.

Comment: They are indeed different paths! `storages` in `storages.py` is referring to itself (the compiled file): `/home/ubuntu/project/core/storages.pyc` while the second `storages` is referring to the package itself: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/storages/__init__.pyc`. So it looks like `storages` that is being imported in `storages.py` is considering itself as the default storage instead of the defined one in `settings.py`, which I don't understand. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I've added a possible solution in an Answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a namespace conflict; the `storage` absolute name clashes with a `storage` local name. It may be unintuitive, but you can import from module in itself:

```
// file my_module/clash.py
import clash
print clash.__file__
```

Now we run python shell in a dir containing a `my_module`:

```
$ python
>>> import my_module.clash
my_module.clash.py
```

In short, your module tries to import a backend from itself.

You need an absolute import - [Trying to import module with the same name as a built-in module causes an import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224741/python-import-with-name-conflicts).

Comment: Thank you, added `from __future__ import absolute_import` and it now works.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue, but for me it turns out that despite `django-storages` being installed, `boto` was not. A simple `pip install boto` fixed the error in my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I had another type of issue that can help others, I used to have another file named `storages.py` but I deleted that file days ago, and still getting the Exception... the thing is I didn't had deleted the file `storages.pyc` !

Comment: Yep, this happened to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typo error.
Change:

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

TO:

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3Boto3Storage'