# Django using S3BotoStorage with multiple buckets

Tags: django, boto, django-storage

I currently have one bucket for static files, this is the `settings.py`:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'leleaseca'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
S3_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

I would like to add another bucket for user uploaded media. It is not clear to me how this can be accomplished. I've found an answer suggesting that there is a way for `S3BotoStorage` to [take the bucket name as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419248/django-storages-with-multiple-s3-buckets). There was no example given for this part, so I imagine it is something like this:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage("bucket1")'
STATIC_URL = 'https://bucket1.s3.amazonaws.com/'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage("bucket2")'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://bucket2.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

I doubt that this is what he meant, but this is in pseudocode what I want to accomplish.